# Android how to reset SCREEN_ALWAYS_ON?

Tags: android

```
public void screenTurnALWAYSON() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

I have this code, this keep the screen always on. How can I reset these settings when I don't need it anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the clearFlags method, f.e.:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WakeLocker.acquire(context);` and `WakeLocker.release();`.
you'll need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` permission.